# Where are blockchain environmental globals stored?

Tags: blockchain, evm, blocks

Where are contract globals like msg.sender and block.number stored?

It is in memory or storage?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I mean information like the "msg.sender" or  "block.number" these are environment variables, we have access to these variables but where they are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't stored in memory *or* the storage. There exists special opcodes in the EVM (machine level instructions) that push the equivalent values to the stack. See page 29 of the of the [whitepaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) to see all of these environment information opcodes.